# dotnet restore fail on Ubuntu20.04 while using dotnet-sdk-5.0

Tags: .net, nuget, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have .NET5.0 application which I'm trying to set up on Ubuntu20.04 under WLS2.

When I run `dotnet restore` command, nuget gives me the following error for all the packages.

```
 Determining projects to restore...
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://coporate_url/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Hostname not found or DNS failed).
```

It looks like a DNS problem, however the command works fine when I run it on dotnet-sdk-3.1. It also works okay when I run it directly on Windows.

I use a VPN to connect to private corporate network, and Nuget.Config is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="company" value="http://corporate_url/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy" value="http://corporate_proxy_ip" />
    <add key="no_proxy" value="corporate_url" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

When I set the resolved company ip address to value property for company package resources, nuget successfully retrieve corporate private packages, but public ones still fail.

Is there anybody having similar problem?

**Expected behavior**

dotnet restore should not fail restoring

**Actual behaivior**

```
 Determining projects to restore...
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://coporate_url/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Hostname not found or DNS failed).
```

**Environment data**

```
dotnet --info output
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.300
 Commit:    2e0c8c940e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.300/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.6
  Commit:  478b2f8c0e

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.409 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.300 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```